# First Step Analysis

Tags: random-walk

Let (Sn)n∈N be a random walk process with increments that are independent.
The value of the random walk increase by one in one time step with probability
p and decrease by one in one time step with probability q = 1 − p. We denote
the hitting time of state 0 to be
T0 = inf{n ≥ 0 : Sn = 0}.

(a) Show that for any i ≥ 1, we have
E[T0|S0 = i] = iE[T0|S0 = 1] ,
and compute E[T0|S0 = 1] for the case q > p and p ≥ q.

(b) Similarly, show that we have,
P(T0 < ∞|S0 = i) = (P(T0 < ∞|S0 = 1))^i , i ≥ 1.

(c) Find P(T0 < ∞|S0 = 1).

Comment: You are expected to tell us what you have done so far and where exactly you have difficulty.

Comment: @Kavi Hi sorry im a new user here. But i am just stuck with this question. I have no idea how to start and do.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).